# Parsing data with python

Tags: python, parsing

I am working to write a program to parse a .txt file.
The .txt data file looks like this:

```
2020062300,TAB
DEBUT20200623
01AAAAA BJAZBACVB.              2012100199991231
01BBBBB BJSSBACVB.              2012100199991231
01SS    BTRFBACVB.              2012100199991231
01D.    BJSSBACVB.              2012100199991231
02AAAAA BJAZBACVB.              2012100199991231
02BBBBB BJSSBACVB.              2012100199991231
03SS    BTRFBACVB.              2012100199991231
03D.    BJSSBACVB.              2012100199991231
FIN20200623
2020062301,TAB
DEBUT20200623
FRAAAAA BJAZ            2012100199991231   
KSBBBBB BJSCVB.         2012100199991231
BBSS    BTRFBACVB.      2012100199991231
SSD.    BJSSBACVB.      2012100199991231
FIN20200623
2020062309,TAB
DEBUT20200623
TOTO    BJAZDGGD          2012100199991231   
TATA    BJSCVBNS          2012100199991231
TITI    BTRFBACV          2012100199991231
TOMA    BJSSBACV          2012100199991231
FIN20200623
```

each part of file was delimited by :
20200623**00**,TAB
**DEBUT**20200623
...
**FIN**20200623

As output, we expected to have 3 objects :
T00_XX with XX: the first two characters for each rows. So we should have three outputs tables:  T00_01, T00_02, T00_03

table **T00_01** :

```
tab, name, des, start_date, end_date
01, AAAAA, BJAZBACVB., 2012100, 199991231
01, BBBBB, BJSSBACVB., 20121001, 99991231
01, SS, BTRFBACVB., 20121001,99991231
01, D., BJSSBACVB., 20121001, 99991231
```

table **T00_02** :

```
tab,name, des,start_date,end_date
02, AAAAA, BJAZBACVB., 20121001, 99991231
02, BBBBB, BJSSBACVB., 20121001, 99991231
```

table **T00_03** :

```
tab, name, des, start_date, end_date
03, SS, BTRFBACVB., 20121001, 99991231
03, D., BJSSBACVB., 20121001, 99991231
03D., BJSSBACVB., 20121001, 99991231
```

20200623**01**,TAB
**DEBUT**20200623

**FIN**20200623

table **T01**

```
name, desc,  start_date, end_date
FRAAAAA, BJAZ, 20121001, 99991231   
KSBBBBB, BJSCVB., 20121001, 99991231
BBSS, BTRFBACVB., 20121001, 99991231
SSD., BJSSBACVB., 20121001, 99991231
```

20200623**09**,TAB
**DEBUT**20200623

**FIN**20200623

table **T09**

```
TOTO, BJAZDGGD, 2012100199991231   
TATA, BJSCVBNS, 2012100199991231
TITI, BTRFBACV, 2012100199991231
TOMA, BJSSBACV, 2012100199991231
```

I started to write a program which for the moment does not meet my needs:

```
%%time
path=r"fichiertest.txt"
data_00_01=[]
with open(path, "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line[8:14])
        if(line[8:13]=="00,TAB"):
            print(line)
            if(line[0:5]=="DEBUT"):
                print(line)
                if(line[0:2]=="01"):
                    print(line)
                    content_00_01 = {}
                    content_00_01["tab"]=line[0:2]
                    content_00_01["nom"]=line[2:8]
                    content_00_01["desc"]=line[8:20]
                    content_00_01["date_debut"]=line[32:40]
                    content_00_01["date_fin"]=line[40:48]
```

The use of if condition does not allow to satisfy the conditions on several lines.

Comment: Looks like your various conditions are alternatives - you probably want `if` ... `elif` ... `elif` (all at the same indentation level) instead of nested `if` statements

Comment: Why did you not continue writing your program until it meets your needs?

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Thank you,
as expected outputs, we expected 5 tables:
T00_01, T00_02, T00_03 for the first block 
2020062300,TAB     
DEBUT20200623      
...      
FIN20200623   
and T01 and T09 for the two other blocks

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's still unclear - you are talking about 3 tables , 5 tables, 5 elements, etc... Instead of describing the output, can you edit the question (that is, not in a comment) and show the **exact** expected output?

Comment: This platform lives from the fact that there are volunteers who are willing to sacrifice their time and use their knowledge to help others to solve their problems. In order to give these people feedback on the success of their measures, the users are given a wide variety of means. It would be nice if the questioner would use this to rate the answer and / or mark the question as answered. Even if you have received an answer, it is always possible to clarify any resulting ambiguities with comments. I hope that you understand my concerns and thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

My solution could certainly be simplified but shows you how it could work.
One or the other regular expression may also have to be adapted to the circumstances.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

def readFile(path):
    data = defaultdict(list)
    with open(path, 'r') as fp:
        while True:
            ln = fp.readline()
            if ln == '': break

            m = re.match(r'^(\d{8})(\d{2}),TAB$', ln.strip())
            if not m: raise OSError('Illegal format')
            id,num = m.groups()

            ln = fp.readline().strip()
            if ln != f'DEBUT{id}': raise OSError('Illegal format')

            while True:
                ln = fp.readline().strip()
                if ln == f'FIN{id}': break
                elif ln == '' or (ln[:3] == 'FIN' and ln[3:] != id): 
                    raise OSError('Illegal format')
                if num == '00':
                    m = re.match(r'^(\d{2})([A-Z\.]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+(\d{8})(\d{8})$', ln)
                    if m:
                        tab,name,desc,start_date,end_date = m.groups()
                        data[f'T{num}_{tab}'].append({
                            # 'tab': tab,
                            'name': name,
                            'desc': desc,
                            'start_date': start_date,
                            'end_date': end_date
                        })
                    else:
                        raise OSError('Illegal format')
                elif num == '01' or num == '09':
                    m = re.match(r'^([A-Z\.]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+(\d{8})(\d{8})$', ln)
                    if m:
                        name,desc,start_date,end_date = m.groups()
                        data[f'T{num}'].append({
                            'name': name,
                            'desc': desc,
                            'start_date': start_date,
                            'end_date': end_date
                        })
                    else:
                        raise OSError('Illegal format')
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
from io import StringIO

txt = '''
2020062300,TAB
DEBUT20200623
01AAAAA BJAZBACVB.              2012100199991231
01BBBBB BJSSBACVB.              2012100199991231
01SS    BTRFBACVB.              2012100199991231
01D.    BJSSBACVB.              2012100199991231
02AAAAA BJAZBACVB.              2012100199991231
02BBBBB BJSSBACVB.              2012100199991231
03SS    BTRFBACVB.              2012100199991231
03D.    BJSSBACVB.              2012100199991231
FIN20200623
2020062301,TAB
DEBUT20200623
FRAAAAA BJAZ            2012100199991231   
KSBBBBB BJSCVB.         2012100199991231
BBSS    BTRFBACVB.      2012100199991231
SSD.    BJSSBACVB.      2012100199991231
FIN20200623
2020062309,TAB
DEBUT20200623
TOTO    BJAZDGGD          2012100199991231   
TATA    BJSCVBNS          2012100199991231
TITI    BTRFBACV          2012100199991231
TOMA    BJSSBACV          2012100199991231
FIN20200623
'''.strip()

tname = ""
all = {}  # dictionary of all tables
for ln in StringIO(txt):   # can also read from file
    ln = ' '.join(ln.split())  # remove extra spaces
    if ',TAB' in ln:   # set table name
       tname='T' + ln[-6:-4]  # 00
       continue
    if ln[:5] == 'DEBUT':  # skip row
       continue
    if ln[:3] == 'FIN':  # end of table
       tname=""
       continue
    if ln[0] == '0':  # table 00
       tname = tname.split('_')[0] + "_" + ln[:2]
       ln = ','.join((ln[:2] + " " + ln[2:-8] + " " + ln[-8:]).split(" "))
       if not tname in all: all[tname]=['tab, name, des, start_date, end_date']
    else:  # other tables
       ln = ','.join((ln[:-8] + " " + ln[-8:]).split(" "))
       if not tname in all: all[tname]=['name, desc,  start_date, end_date']
    all[tname].append(ln)

# print tables
for t in all:
   print(t)
   for r in all[t]:
      print(r)
```